# Create effect similar to Twitter's retweet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm sorry I didn't provide any specifics - I'm writing a Twitter like application for our school project, and I'm kinda stuck - how do you create a pop over like Twitter's retweet function? Here's my initial thoughts so far:

1.The retweet div and the blackout is a separate HTML page

2.The retweet content is directly copied from the tweet where retweet is clicked (but how? Should this be fetched with PHP? Or is this directly "copied" from the tweet with jQuery? If so, some pointers please?)

3.And I have no idea how the page appears *on top of* the page. I'm thinking of something like

```
$("#retweet").on('click', function() {
    // something that loads the page on top of the page? 
});
```

1.How do I "load" this page on top without reloading the page?

2.Is AJAX involved? (Sorry, I'm not too familiar.)

3.How do I pass variables between the page and the popup page? (This is what I was referring to in question 2 - if the retweeted box is a reconstruction based on the tweet, then how is this fetched?)

I'd appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the http://bootboxjs.com library? Try it out, it seems similar to the tweeter retweet. 
Take time to read the doc to find out how to install and use it, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Here could be an example:

```
$("#retweet").on('click', function() {
      bootbox.confirm("Retweet this?" + $("#idOfTextToRetweet").text(), function(result) {
             if(result) {
                   //perform the retweet
             }
      });
});
```

I hope this helps !